# Why my window resize event listener doesn't work? Using Three.js and Vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, three.js, vuetify.js

I am putting a three.js renderer inside of a , using vuetify.js framework. What I would like my code to do is to change the div element dimensions whenever the window is resized.

This is part of my project and I omitted unnecessary code blocks, so don't mind the not used variables :)

```
<style scoped>
.map__three {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 0px;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div class="flex fill-height wrap">
    <v-btn></v-btn>
    <div id="map"  class="flex fill-height wrap"  v-on:dblclick="addNewPoi3d"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'ThreeTest',
  data() {
    return {
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      camera: null,
      mouse: null,
      mousePosition: new THREE.Vector2(),
      canvasPosition: null,
      rayCaster: new THREE.Raycaster(),
      mapWidth: null,
      mapHeight: null,
      mapDimensions: null
    };
  },

  methods: {
    init() {
      let map = document.getElementById('map');
      this.mapDimensions = map.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.mapWidth = this.mapDimensions.width;
      this.mapHeight = this.mapDimensions.height;
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );

      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        this.mapWidth/this.mapHeight,
        0.1,
        1000,
      );
      this.camera.position.z = 3;


      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      this.renderer.setSize(this.mapWidth, this.mapHeight);
      map.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);



      // EVENT LISTENERS:
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize, false);
    },


    onWindowResize()  {
        this.camera.aspect = this.mapWidth / this.mapHeight;
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        this.renderer.setSize(this.mapWidth, this.mapHeight);
    },



    animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
      this.render();
    },
    render() {
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    },

  },

  mounted() {
    this.init();
    this.animate();
  }
};
</script>
```

EXPECTED: it should resize the dimensions of the scene and camera aspect ratio I've loaded in.

WHAT IT DOES: none of that :D It pertains the same size of the scene and camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to re-calculate `this.mapWidth` and `this.mapHeight` in the `onWindowResize()` function. At the moment, the code sets the camera and renderer to the size the app was initially loaded at.

Try this:

```
onWindowResize()  {
  let map = document.getElementById('map');
  this.mapDimensions = map.getBoundingClientRect();
  this.mapWidth = this.mapDimensions.width;
  this.mapHeight = this.mapDimensions.height;

  this.camera.aspect = this.mapWidth / this.mapHeight;
  this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  this.renderer.setSize(this.mapWidth, this.mapHeight);
},
```